# How do I generate a dynamic connection string in Entity Framework 4?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

Is it possible to choose a specific database that will be used with the entity framework?
At this time, I use the connection string in the Web.Config as database authentication.

I have twelve databases, each of them has the same structure and the same stored procedure.

There is one database for each client. When a client wants to login into the system, he needs to choose his database name from a listbox.

I would like to create a dynamic connection string which will include the database name chosen by the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method might be to load all the 12 choices in a dropdownlist.

When the user makes a choice, put that key into `Session`.

```
 Session["UserChosenConnString"] = Request.Form("ddMyDatabaseTarget");
```

Then supply that conn string to your repo/data layer at runtime.

```
 string connString = Session["UserChosenConnString"].ToString();
 var db = new CustomerEntities(connString);
```

There are lots of opportunities to improve this:

- store the 12 choices in a `KeyValuePair<int,string>`, and store only the key integer in `Session`. Then look up the value when hitting the database.

Comment: what is the format of the connString that I should pass to the CustomerEntities

Comment: How about Win App ? I'm facing the same issue